# Complex HTML structure in ngRepeat with a deep Scope object makes things slow

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

this is more asking for opinions or some solutions people may have come across. I render a list of airline Itineraries based on a $scope object fetched via an API. All in all there can be up to 150 in an array that I loop through and display on the page. These Itineraries are relatively complex/heavy on the HTML/CSS front thanks to our wonderful design agency. The itineraries include about 20+ properties I use during the ngRepeat. For example flight time, destination, stopovers etc. The actual Itinerary object is quite deep, but I limit my loops to 3-4. and try to get to properties based on direct access journey[0]/journey[index] whenever possible, rather than using another Repeat on child objects. There are occasions though where this is not possible and I have to loop again.

My Issue is my repeat is getting very slow. The page struggles to load and scrolling is equally as laggy. Basically not usable at the minute. I guess I am trying to figure out some best practices for using multiple nested repeats, followed by complex HTML structures.

Thank you for the help in advance.

Comment: you could use one-way binding to prevent DOM rerender

Comment: @MarkoCen currently I just place info into the partial like so. {{someInfo}}. the itineraries are passed in simply by applying them to $scope.Itineraries. I initially have to loop through them all, so not sure if this would be applicable?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a virtual repeater. You can use one of the solutions out there in the web or bake one of your own creation.

The idea is simple, you only render an small number of "rows" (element to repeat) at a time.

I know that sometimes this get tricky so I have an small gist with a simplerepeater out there in github

You can find it here: https://gist.github.com/scyrizales/f2a297db522e2d789f69f70e7151ce7e

The idea is to replace your ng-repeat with virtual-repeat:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in collection"></div>
```

to this:

```
<div virtual-repeat="item in collection"></div>
```

I recommend that you use it only in your outer repeater and my solution only allow repeat over arrays (so collection should be an array)

I hope this help you :)

Comment: Thank you, I will have a look. Take care